# LINQ All not working as expected when used with Contains

Tags: c#, linq

I have a many-to-many relationship like this:

Organisations (OrganisationID, Name)
Categories (CategoryID, Name)
Organisations_Categories (OrganisationID, CategoryID)

I'm trying to get a list of Organisations that belong to *all* the Categories that get passed in as a parameter

e.g. If 10 Organisations belong to CategoryID=1, and 0 Organisations belong to CategoryID=2, and I pass in [1,2] as the CategoryID parameter, 0 Organisations should be returned, because 0 Organisations belong to both CategoryID=1 and CategoryID=2

Here is the code so far:

```
int[] catIdsSelected = ((catIds.Length > 0) ? Array.ConvertAll(catIds.Split(','), int.Parse) : new int[0]);

if (catIdsSelected.Length > 0)
{
    orgs = orgs.Where(l => l.Categories.Any(m => catIdsSelected.AsQueryable().Contains(m.CategoryID)));
}
```

However this returns a list of Organisations that belong to *any* of the Categories passed in

I've tried replacing 'Any' with 'All' without success

Comment: Please test as using List<int> catIdsSelected = ....     and tell me result.

Comment: Just tried making it a List instead of IQueryable - same result

Comment: @user982119, try change where condition: `orgs = orgs.Where(l => catIdsSelected.AsQueryable().All(ID => l.Categories.Any(ct => ct.CategoryID == ID)));`

Comment: @ASh I am almost 100% sure that `All` is not supported by EF.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a little trick:

```
if (catIdsSelected.Length > 0)
{
    foreach (var id in carIdsSelected)
    {
       var localId = id;
       orgs = orgs.Where(o => o.Categories.Any(cat => cat.CategoryId == localId));
    }
}
```

It will work for sure, but I am not sure how efficient query is generated by EF provider.

Comment: That's pretty good. Guess I would have thought of that eventually, thanks a lot :)